# laravel redirect back to post route, i get MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, http, redirect, post

At first on a get request i show a form, on submitting it, it goes to a post url does some working in the controller and then returns another view which has a form. after submitting this form i validate some things and if the validation fails i want to redirect back with some errors but unfortunately laravel isn't allowing me 
 to redirect back to a post method. Is there any way i can accomplish this?

i have seen this answer on laracast https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/redirect-back-to-post-route-i-get-methodnotallowed-exception but i couldn't grasp the recommendation

these are my routes in the order described above.

```
  Route::get('/purchasePacks', 'masterDealerController@purchasePacks')->name('purchasePacks');
  Route::post('/confirmPuchasedPacks','masterDealerController@confirmPuchasedPacks');
  Route::post('/storeOrder','masterDealerController@storeOrder');
```

below is the redirection code in the storeOrder method. which redirects back to the post url
```

```
Alert::message("Unable to complete your payment at the moment.",'Please try again later.',"error");
        return back()->withInput();
```

```

Comment: Post Redirect Get

Comment: `which redirects back to the post url ?` redirect always performed on GET request. You can't redirect to `/storeOrder` because it is POST request.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are sending a GET request to a POST route. You could do one of a few things that I can think of.

1)
In your controller you can have a static method, storeOrderRedirect(), that handles whatever you need it to on the redirect.

```
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), '/storeOrder', function()
{
   App\Http\Controllers\masterDealerController::storeOrderRedirect()
});
```

2)
Just have a post and a get route

3)
I myself would send the data from the form via ajax and not leave the page until I get the response I was looking for instead of using  redirects and leaving the page to begin with.